# Does Postgresql have any tools that translates a schema creation script to a dump form?

Tags: postgresql

Given some create table script as

```
create table t_foo (
    id bigserial primary key,
    bar_id bigserial references t_bar
)
```

Postgresql will automatically create the primary key and foreign key that I can see if I pg_dump the schema.

Is there a way for me to get the final schema creation script without having to run the initial script on a real db and dumping it?

Comment: You'll also need the definition of the t_bar table, plus the column in t_bar referenced by bar_id - it has to be `UNIQUE NOT NULL` (IIRC).

Comment: @ibrabeicker, Postgresql will automatically create the primary key and foreign key that I can see if I pg_dump the schema. No. (I mean to say that user created db)